# Who are some of the Test Automation experts that are well-known and respected in Software Industry?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, test-automation-framework

I am a complete beginner in Test Automation and was looking for some world experts on this subject.

Could you list or refer to material of some of the best known experts in Automation industry who have written books, Blogs or articles, that can really help newbie like me get started about automation in general.

I want to follow their advice, so that i have a direction to move.

Answer (score 4):

Test Automation on itself should not be a field if you ask me, therefor it is mostly software developers (that value automated testing highly) who write  books/articles that drive the field. Because very good software developers are also very good testers.

**Kent Beck:**

My personal favorite is [Kent Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) and his book Test-Driven Development.

> **Beck** was one of the 17 original signatories of the Agile Manifesto,
>   the founding document for agile software development. Extreme and
>   Agile methods are closely associated with **Test-Driven Development
>   (TDD)**, of which Beck is perhaps the leading proponent.

After nearly 20 years Beck is still experimenting and writing about with new software development test technique's. I like his recent princibles for programmer tests: https://medium.com/@kentbeck_7670/programmer-test-principles-d01c064d7934

- https://twitter.com/KentBeck

**James Shore**:

James is very active and his *Lets code* video's are all about how to build a paint/drawing application while automating everything, and starting with tests, also covering automated deployments and build pipelines.

- http://www.letscodejavascript.com/
- https://www.jamesshore.com/Agile-Book/
- https://twitter.com/jamesshore?lang=en

**Harry Percival**:

His Python TDD book takes you on a practical journey to automate and build a Todo-list application from scratch. Starting with a failing Selenium test until you automatically deploy to cloud infrastructure. This all with very detailed steps, code and lots of background and learnings.

- http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/
- https://twitter.com/hjwp

Comment: I would add Jason Huggins the first developer of Selenium simply for his influence on the industry

Comment: @Thanks Neils and Rsf for your suggestions. I have looked upon websites of these people and will read their material regularly to upgrade my skills.

Comment: Are there any experts in Selenium Webdriver as well, apart from Jason Huggins who have useful material?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Alan Richardson](http://eviltester.com) who has a lot of online courses - mostly Java focussed and also useful for newbies (they are up-to-date and he provides coaching as well), books and is a general nice guy (not important in itself ;-) )

Another would be [Richard Bradshaw](https://thefriendlytester.co.uk/) who ticks the same boxes. Richard also provides several free online courses.

*Both are testers who code*